# Why alpine-base 3.5.1 downgrade to 3.5.0 when I change to edge repository?

Tags: alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

I'm following https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Edge to upgrade alpine 3.5.1 to edge. The /etc/apk/repository is

```
http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
@testing http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing
```

And I do the following command:

```
apk upgrade --update-cache --available
```

Then my alpine is back to 3.5.0

```
cat /etc/alpine-release
3.5.0
```

If I change the /etc/apk/repository to

```
http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main
http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
@testing http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing
```

It back to 3.5.1, but gdk-pixbuf downgrading from 2.36.5-r0 -> 2.36.2-r0

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Edge always reports 3.5.0. So that version number may not be reliable. I would say that this is standard for development versions.

```
$ docker run alpine:3.4 cat /etc/alpine-release
3.4.6

$ docker run alpine:edge cat /etc/alpine-release
3.5.0
```